# Oracle - LISTAGG issues

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'm running Oracle

```
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
Production    PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production    "CORE 
12.2.0.1.0 - Production"    TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

The issue I'm facing is, again, with `LISTAGG` and `SUBSTR`.

In the below sqlfiddles the are two sqls, I did the first `SELECT DISTINCT` just to show me that all works as expected. Then in the second I'm adding `LISTAGG` to group and put commas etc. and to have all values in one row.

In the following sqlfiddle I get an error "invalid identifier"
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf13785/1

while this next works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf13785/13 but it does not give the expected result as if the `SUBSTR` function is not considered and the `wdocname` field is read in its integrity. You see in the fiddle that some values are duplicated.

I  know that this sounds like a duplicate question, but I've been reading all `LISTAGG` posts and I did not come to a point.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There's no alias `ordref` in the `from/join` clause in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is an *invalid identifier* as you're now querying a **subquery**, not original table.

Should be

```
SQL> SELECT LISTAGG (CHR (39) || docs || CHR (39), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY docs) result
  2    FROM (
  3            SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (ordref.wdocname, 1, 5) AS docs
  4              FROM ordref
  5         );

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'AM00A', 'AN00C', 'AS00A', 'AV00A', 'AV00B', 'BC00A', 'ER00B', 'IV00C', 'OD00B',
 'OV00A', 'OV00C', 'SL00B', 'TR00B', 'VL00B'


SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome.